# Kitten always gets dirty from stool

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, defecation

I have approx 3 month old kitten. After poo it usually put hands on the stool and hands get dirty.

It is really annoying because then it roams around and smell is everywhere, is it due to the size of litter box? Does it need more space? The litter box is kind of a tub, round, and triple the length of kitten.

Sometimes I just pick it up as he is done with poo and I put the sand over the poo. Need guidance. It is my first pet.

Comment: What is the litter you are using and the size of litter box

Comment: it is kind of a tub , round , and triple the length of kitten, may i know average size of litter

Comment: And what litter are you using?

Comment: Best idea is to go to amazon pet section and search for big litter box and quality litter.

Comment: @DaniyalJavaid as a new pet owner, please stay active on the site, we also have a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) you can visit and get to know other animal lovers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the kitty litter tray is too small. Cats naturally like to cover up their faeces, and will dig and push dirt or kitty litter to cover it. It doesn't sound like she has much room to do this. She could be getting faeces on her paws attempting to cover it, or just by trying to exit the litter box.

I suspect a rectangular shape may be easier for your kitten to use, than a round shape.

Go for a minimum size or 345 mm wide  x 440 mm high  x 125 mm  deep.

For example:

[image]

Cats are pretty clean creatures and she wouldn't like having faeces on her front paws. Most importantly, be patient with her and gently clean her paws with a damp warm cloth. She cannot help that this is happening. It's always the humans who are responsible for their pets behaviours.

The other issue is also to consider, her stools may be too runny. Either way, she needs a bigger litter box.

Here are some useful posts to help you get started:

[How often should a litter box be cleaned?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16766/how-often-should-a-litter-box-be-cleaned)

[How can I reduce litter/waste odor?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10516/how-can-i-reduce-litter-waste-odor)

[Cat digs litter out of the box](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/288/cat-digs-litter-out-of-the-box)

[What types of kitty litter are there and what else can be used as kitty litter?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18298/what-types-of-kitty-litter-are-there-and-what-else-can-be-used-as-kitty-litter)